# Is it possible html tags in plist file?

Tags: iphone, plist

i downloads strings from web in plist format.
a simple example:

```
.....
<dict>
<key>title</title>
<string>Title is here</string>
</dict>
.....
```

some title comes with html tags;some title has & char.

```
<b>Title & Title is here</b>
```

thats why my plist format crashes.

it is not possible to convert records on the server. because there is running website.

i make my plist file with below code:

```
NSData *plistData=[request responseData];
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *error;
NSMutableArray *plist;
plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData 
                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                   format:&format errorDescription:&error];
```

how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to XML encode your string, & will become & amp ;

Comment: how can i encode it? i can take my data in nsstring format too. NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);